# Prevent scrolling in background

Tags: javascript, scroll

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('UI').className = "open";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('UI').className = "closed";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 75px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#UI {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .5s;
}
#UI.closed {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
}
#UI.open {
  background-color: rgba(05, 55, 105, .75);
}
#UI button {
  font-size: 30;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
}
#UI button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px blue;
}
#openNavBtn {
  top: 5px;
}
#topBtn {
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .5s;
}
#closeNavBtn {
  position: fixed;
  left: -50px;
}
#UI.closed #openNavBtn {
  left: 5px;
}
#UI.closed #topBtn {
  right: 5px;
}
#UI.closed #nav {
  left: -300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}
#UI.closed #closeNavBtn {
  left: -50px;
}
#UI.open #openNavBtn {
  left: -55px;
}
#UI.open #topBtn {
  right: -55px;
}
#UI.open #nav {
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}
#UI.open #closeNavBtn {
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="UI" class="closed">
    <div id="nav">
      <button id="closeNavBtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <button id="openNavBtn" onclick="openNav();">&#9776;</button>
    <button id="topBtn">&#8613;</button>
  </div>
  <h1>SCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLL
```

Using the current code, the body scrolls while the `nav` is open -- How do I prevent this?

P.S. Pardon my clustered coding style. If anyone has any advice on how to keep it clean, please do share.

P.P.S. I've already asked my entire question, yet it says I need more details. How should I avoid this in the future?

Comment: What do you want to do? You want to have a floating popup window, and disable scrolling when the popup window is open?

Answer (score 1):

You could make your nav toggle also add and remove a class on body, and use that to set `overflow: hidden` on the body tag, if this is what you're requesting:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('UI').className = "open";
  document.body.className = 'navopen';
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('UI').className = "closed";
  document.body.className = '';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 75px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
body.navopen {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#UI {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .5s;
}
#UI.closed {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
}
#UI.open {
  background-color: rgba(05, 55, 105, .75);
}
#UI button {
  font-size: 30;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
}
#UI button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px blue;
}
#openNavBtn {
  top: 5px;
}
#topBtn {
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .5s;
}
#closeNavBtn {
  position: fixed;
  left: -50px;
}
#UI.closed #openNavBtn {
  left: 5px;
}
#UI.closed #topBtn {
  right: 5px;
}
#UI.closed #nav {
  left: -300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}
#UI.closed #closeNavBtn {
  left: -50px;
}
#UI.open #openNavBtn {
  left: -55px;
}
#UI.open #topBtn {
  right: -55px;
}
#UI.open #nav {
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}
#UI.open #closeNavBtn {
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="UI" class="closed">
    <div id="nav">
      <button id="closeNavBtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <button id="openNavBtn" onclick="openNav();">&#9776;</button>
    <button id="topBtn">&#8613;</button>
  </div>
  <h1>SCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLL
```

Comment: You can still scroll the page, this just hides the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

You may toggle `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'`; in your open/closeNav functions:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('UI').className = "open";
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('UI').className = "closed";
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 75px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#UI {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .5s;
}
#UI.closed {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
}
#UI.open {
  background-color: rgba(05, 55, 105, .75);
}
#UI button {
  font-size: 30;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
}
#UI button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px blue;
}
#openNavBtn {
  top: 5px;
}
#topBtn {
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .5s;
}
#closeNavBtn {
  position: fixed;
  left: -50px;
}
#UI.closed #openNavBtn {
  left: 5px;
}
#UI.closed #topBtn {
  right: 5px;
}
#UI.closed #nav {
  left: -300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}
#UI.closed #closeNavBtn {
  left: -50px;
}
#UI.open #openNavBtn {
  left: -55px;
}
#UI.open #topBtn {
  right: -55px;
}
#UI.open #nav {
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}
#UI.open #closeNavBtn {
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="UI" class="closed">
    <div id="nav">
      <button id="closeNavBtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <button id="openNavBtn" onclick="openNav();">&#9776;</button>
    <button id="topBtn">&#8613;</button>
  </div>
  <h1>SCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLLSCROLL
```

Comment: You can still scroll the page, this just hides the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running preventDefaults on the body scroll event like this when the UI is open?

```
$("body").scroll(function(e){ 
  if($("#UI").hasClass("open"))
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Might be worth noting that this solution requires JQuery